# Saving original order of keys in Dictionary by parsing JSONschema in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, jsonschema

In my project I have to parse JSON schema, that comes from server.
It has object "Properties", which in fact like `Dictionary` in curly braces. And, of course, `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` parses it as `Dictionary`.

Everything looks like OK, **BUT**: I use these Properties for building my view (it defines fields to be fiiled by user). Finally, I have to save **order** of these fields! But, as we know, immediately after the object is parsed to Dictionary, it looses keys order. Anybody knows how can I parse these object, saving fields order?

**Additional information:**

Structure of Properties is build by user in WEB, so their count is avsolutely random for mobile client. Furthermore, Every object in properties (e.g. Group) **can** have its own properties, containing other objects. So we have absolutely random tree of nested objects. And their order is necessary for us.

[image]

Comment: It is a bad idea to rely on the order of key-value pairs in a JSON object. Compare http://www.json.org: *"An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs."*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about interoperability, meaning 3rd parties also being able to rely on order, you can try to find a parser that preserves order (such as by reading it into an OrderedMap in Python instead of a regular dict- obviously this will differ by language.)

If you care about 3rd parties, it's trickier.  As the last person to respond noted, JSON itself does not support this, and JSON Schema is just JSON as far as parsing goes.